# How to set the logo icon on the Firebase Dynamic Link preview page?

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm setting up the Firebase Dynamic Link and its preview page, but non of any instruction about setting the logo icon.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U5V9.jpg
The red AppTitle is modified, and actually the black color, the logo icon should be next to it and at the left side.

My project is developing in android, iOS and javascript website, I've search many documents and SDK functions, but haven't seen the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fund the answer from the Firebase supporting,
the logo icon will be showing after available in the Apple Store/Google play :)